# Counter won't increment more than once onclick

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a counter that onclick should increment 1 and it does that on click, but if I click the button again, it won't increment again. Instead it will be stuck at 1. How can I make it go up if the button is clicked more than once?

```
 protected void submitAnswerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
  int counter = 0;
  if (mathAnswerTextBox.Text == answer.ToString())
        {
            answerStatus.Text = "Correct!";


        }
        else if (mathAnswerTextBox.Text != answer.ToString())
        {

            answerStatus.Text = "Incorrect";
            counter++;



            if (counter == 1)
            {

                incorrectStrikes.Text = counter.ToString();
            }
            else if (counter == 2)
            {
                incorrectStrikes.Text = counter.ToString();

            }
            else if (counter == 3)
            {
                incorrectStrikes.Text = counter.ToString();

            }
        }
```

Comment: move the `int counter` outside the method.

Comment: @Sayse I doubt that this will be *the* solution. There's still a difference between instance- and static-member ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair - what does that have to do with it? - Also OP you may wish to read this - [Variable and Method Scope in Microsoft .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

Comment: @Sayse read the question again: "but if I click the button again, it won't increment again." ... so you need a thread-indepentend value and somehow attach subsequent clicks to the correct *instance*  (eg ThreadStatic, which won't work in web-context)

Comment: study about variable scope: https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100502135419AAzJjtW

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair - we don't know what sort of application the OP is building. Their terminology *might* be construed as indicating it's a web app but that's by no means certain (and if it is, then `Session` is the obvious location to pick to solve the issue)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair - with local variables, when you invoke the method, they are reinitialised (and redeclared), class level variables retain their value along with the class, perhaps you may benefit from reading the above link too? I can guarrantee that will be the issue here.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever woho - look at the signature. Anyway - if we don't know the context, @Sayse s comment is not less incomplete. And again, I doubt that `Session` is correct: Imagine a user has 2 tabs with the same url - what would be the desired behaviour?

Comment: It's a web application. Sorry for not saying before.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to make `counter` outside of the method, <strike>such as a [field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173118(v=vs.80).aspx) in the class, not a local variable:</strike>

```
private int counter = 0;
protected void submitAnswerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (mathAnswerTextBox.Text == answer.ToString())
    {
        answerStatus.Text = "Correct!";
  ...
```

Since this is a web application you'd probably want to store the counter in the [session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx), something like:

Inside `Page_Load`:

```
if(!IsPostback)
{
   Session["AttemptCount"] = 0
}
```

And then inside

```
protected void submitAnswerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int counter = (int)Session["AttemptCount"];
  if (mathAnswerTextBox.Text == answer.ToString())
    {
        answerStatus.Text = "Correct!";
  ...

  //Make sure you include this on all paths through this method that
  //affect counter
  Session["AttemptCount"] = counter;
```

Comment: @Sayse I doubt that this will be *the* solution. There's still a difference between instance- and static-member. And a static has the problem of the thread-context (and subsequent thread contexts...)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, OP haven't mentioned that which context this code goes. If OP is using ASP.NET (as correct pointed by Damien) then he can manage it using any state management (preferably session) (OR) if he using Winform then probably declare a static variable.

Comment: You'd rather describe the "downside" of session: It is available to every tab of a browser-instance and you can't distinguish between them - so a user with multiple tabs will update the value cross-wise - and one tab doing POSTs while the other one doing GETs will result in resetting the session-value every GET-request...

Answer (score 3):

As it stands you `counter` is a local variable (as in below code) and so every time you click button it will get initialized to `0` and hence you get `1` every time cause it's getting incremented once.

```
 protected void submitAnswerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
  int counter = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store the value in a more global context, eg [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) or [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx) or maybe even a [HiddenField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield(v=vs.110).aspx) for storage of the value.

Conclusio: Web is stateless so you'd need a state-manager.

```
protected void submitAnswerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var counter = this.ViewState["foo"] as int; // read it from the ViewState from the previous request, or set it to default(int) = 0 with as
    // ... do your routine
    this.ViewState["foo] = counter; // write it back to store it for the next request
}
```

Anyway - this is just valid in a web-context where you are stateless.

If you were in a webform/wpf-context you would rather go for a simple `static`, or instance-variable, or ... (whatever suits your current need, architecture, ...)